# How to implement Multi Connect using WiFi Direct

Tags: android, eclipse, one-to-many, wifi-direct

I am developing an Android app where I want to share content with more than two devices using WiFi Direct. I am able to search for all the available devices but connect to only one. I want to connect to all the available devices that is I want to know how can I make multi connect using WiFi Direct?

http://anrg.usc.edu/ee579_2012/Group09/#wifidirect
I have used this link to make single connection.
Please tell if I can make connection with more than one device.

Answer (score 0):

You can make multiple connections only if you are the group owner.If you are able to connect to only one device that means you are not the group owner. The device that you are connecting to is the group owner and can further connect to other devices.